# How to stop going to next page after session expired?

Tags: php, session, redirect

In quiz task, I have done the time set for each page when I refresh  the page 
 it expires after 1 minute. But after 1 minute without refreshing the page if I click next, it is going to the next quiz page. I can stop this from going to next page.
here is my code

```
    <html>
<head>
<style>
#user
{



color:blue;
font-size:16px;
}
#pass
{

color:blue;
font-size:16px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<form action="quizpage2.php" method="post">
<tr>
<td><div id="user">Username:</div></td></br>
<td><input type="text" name="user"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><div id="pass">Password:</div></td>
<td><input type="text" name="pass"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input  type="submit" value="submit"></td>
</tr>

</form>
</table>
</body>
</html>

page2

session_start();

$AB=$_POST["user"];

$CD=$_POST["pass"];


$_SESSION["new"]=$AB;


$EF=array("paul", "andrew", "steven" ,"don");

$GH=array(123,    456,    789,      000);

if(($AB==$EF[0])&&($CD==$GH[0]))
{

$_SESSION["new"]=$EF[0];
$_SESSION["start"]=time();
$_SESSION["expire"]=$_SESSION["start"]+(1*60);

echo "<script> alert('login successfull')</script>";
echo "<script>window.location.assign('quizpage3.php')</script>";
}
?>





page3-

<?php



session_start();



if(!isset($_SESSION["new"]))
{
echo"<p align='center';>Please login Again";
echo"<a href='quizpage1.php'>Click here</a></p>";
//header("location:quizpage1.php");
}

else
{
$now=time();

if($now>$_SESSION['expire'])
{
session_destroy();
echo"<p align='centre;'>your session is expired!<a href='quizpage1.php'>Login Here</a></p>";
echo"<span style='float:right;'><a href='logoutpage.php'>Logout</a></span>";
}


else
{

echo"<html>";
echo"<head>";
echo"<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>";
echo"<script>

 $(document).ready(function() {
window.history.forward(1);
});

</script>";


echo"<style>
    #sun
    {
        background-color:lightblue;
        width:60%;
    }

</style>";


echo"</head>";
echo"<body>";

echo"<form action='quizpage4.php' method='post'>";

echo"<div id='sun'>";
echo"<tr>";
echo"<td>Which of the following part of the Sun is visible by human?</td></br>";
echo"<td><input type='radio' name='sun' value='Photosphere'>Photosphere</td>.</br>";
echo"<td><input type='radio' name='sun' value='Corona'>Corona</td>.</br>";
echo"<td><input type='radio' name='sun' value='Chromosphere'>Chromosphere</td>.</br>";
echo"<td><input type='radio' name='sun' value='Core'>Core</td>.</br>";
 echo"</tr>";

echo"<tr>";

echo"<td><input type='submit' value='Nextpage'></td>";

echo"</tr>";
echo"</div>";
echo"</form>";

echo"</table>";
echo"</body>";
echo"</html>";

}

}


?>




    enter code here

Logoutpage-

<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("location:quizpage1.php");
?>de here
```

I have 7 quiz page once each quiz page refreshed after one minute it is going back to the login page but without refreshing if click next button after one minute it is going to next quiz page. I want to stop this going to next quiz page after 1 minute. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have use `session time expire` to `re-login`

if page refresh whole call reload and check your time expiry

```
$now=time();

if($now>$_SESSION['expire'])
{
session_destroy();
echo"<p align='centre;'>your session is expired!<a href='quizpage1.php'>Login Here</a></p>";
echo"<span style='float:right;'><a href='logoutpage.php'>Logout</a></span>";
}
```

but when you click `next button` after one minute its every time access next page because
your form was submit and its action call and goes to next page every time after session time was expiry

```
echo"<form action='quizpage4.php' method='post'>";
```

mistake is here your form action called on button click and next page access without checking `session`

so you need to remove `form action` like `action=""` and add name of `next button` like

```
echo"<td><input type='submit' value='Nextpage' name='submit'></td>";
```

and check button is click and session not expire than next page call

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo "<script>window.location.assign('quizpage4.php')</script>";
}
```

> OR

check `time expiry` on `quizpage2.php` starting and reload login page

```
$now=time();

if($now>$_SESSION['expire'])
{
    //echo 1;exit;
    session_destroy();
    echo"<p align='centre;'>your session is expired!<a href='quizpage1.php'>Login Here</a></p>";
    echo"<span style='float:right;'><a href='logoutpage.php'>Logout</a></span>";
}
```